# How to setup Git in Dev Cpp IDE

Tags: git, cvs, sourceforge

I use Dev-Cpp IDE for C programming.

How to setup CVS in sourceforge as I only find Git, SVN, mercurial.. 
(I am new to project hosting things..)

Actually, Dev-Cpp has CVS option.. can't I setup Git in it..

Comment: CVS, as many would tell you, is not longer recommended as a control system. Subversion was born with the idea of being CVS but better and it achieved that goal. Although many people would recommend using Git or mercurial these days. (I won't go there since you can find lots of information about these new systems pros and cons.
There are externals tools like TortoiseSVN, TortoiseGit and TortoiseHG (among many others) that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dev-Cpp IDE](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html) has CVS support, as does [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/CVS).  But it doesn't support Git directly.
[This Dev-Cpp thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/forums/forum/48211/topic/999279) illustrates a setup with cvs.sourceforge.net.

> - Tools menu > Environment options > cvs support tab, browse to your installation of cvs
> - cvs menu > checkout > repository tab:

```
repository: :pserver:anonymous@cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/dev-cpp
access method: pserver
server: cvs.sourceforge.net
remote directory: /cvsroot/dev-cpp
```

> - switch to checkout options:

```
Module name: V5/devcpp.exe
recurse into subdirectories: NOT checked
checkout directory: browse to where you want stuff saved.
```

> - Click 'ok' button

More informations on the **[Dev-Cpp CVS page](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=10639)**.